# Find assembly name from CallerFilePathAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have a class

```
public class DataLayerFromOutside
{
    public string DataLayerMethod(string dataLayerMethodParameter)
    {
        NLogging.Info("FromMethod");
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

This class is within  `SampleClassLibrary`.
I have a controller from which this method is called.

```
[LogActionFilter]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/sample
    public string Get()
    {
        DataLayerFromOutside businessLayer = new DataLayerFromOutside();
        NLogging.Info("Info ");
        return businessLayer.DataLayerMethod("Hi");
    }
```

This controller is within another dll `'TestLoggingEntryAndExit'`.

I have an `NLogging` class where we log all activities.This class contains a method

```
public static void Info(string message, Exception exception = null, [CallerFilePathAttribute] string callerPath = "", [CallerMemberName] string callerMember = "", [CallerLineNumber] int callerLine = 0)
{
    Log(LogLevel.Info, message,null, exception, callerPath, callerMember, callerLine);
}
```

I want to find the assembly name from which this Info method is called.

How can I find the assembly name from `CallerFilePathAttribute`?

Comment: In the general case, you can't get the assembly name from the CallerFilePathAttribute. It is just the full path to the file at compile time. It might not even contain the assembly's name anywhere in the path. You'd have to use a class like StackTrace to get the caller's assembly name.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the caller info attributes. There is [a feature request for more caller info attributes on the backlog of Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/351)

Currently the only way is to use reflection:

```cs
//get assembly of caller
var assembly = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1, false).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Assembly;
```

This isn't possible in .NET standard (.NET Core) yet. It should be there in Netstandard 2.0

edit: @Eilon is right. This isn't a reliable way. Adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` is helping a lot, but no guarantees

edit 2: another reliable way (and more complicated), is to write/use a Fody plugin. See [Fody website](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)

Comment: Use StackFrame is not reliable because some callstacks can be optimized out of the system, so beware. The only reliable way to know the caller's assembly is to have them actually pass it in (if you trust them to do so correctly!). Of course, that isn't always an option due to other constraints.